# cream of chicken soup

Tags: parsing

I'm wondering how to parse the term "cream of chicken soup."

Should it be **cream [of chicken soup]** or **[cream of chicken] soup**? Either way, it doesn't seem to make sense.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I think of it like '*creamy* [chicken soup]'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ((cream (of chicken)) soup). It may help to visualize it as "cream-of-chicken soup" (with hyphens) although it is usually **not** actually written with hyphens. Such a soup is a cream soup, and the cream is made from (for example) chicken stock, milk, a thickening agent and seasoning.

Wikipedia [lists many other "cream of X" soups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_soups#Cream); some of my personal favorites are:

- Cream of mushroom soup
- Cream of asparagus soup
- Cream of broccoli soup

Comment: Cream of Tomato soup (Heinz) with ham/cheese/ham+cheese sandwiches is one of my favourites!

Comment: The cream is not made from chicken, in the case of cream of chicken soup. It is added externally.

Comment: @Apollyon I said chicken stock, not chicken... here's a recipe: https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/211123/cream-of-chicken-soup-from-scratch/

Comment: How about the cream in cream of broccoli soup?

Comment: @Apollyon Well, cream of broccoli soup can be made from milk, flour, broccoli and optional seasoning (onion, celery, etc.). The mixture is blended and cooked to reduce it to a thick creamy soup. "Cream" here refers to the thick, smooth consistency of the result. So all you need to make "cream of X soup" is a base ingredient that can be blended/boiled/cooked with some liquid (often milk) and a thickener (usually flour). Of course, most Americans buy "cream of X soup" in mass-produced cans at the supermarket.